# why do AppDelegate being declared again at AppDelegate.m

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm just a newbie who follow iOS dev, and when I create new single application by using Xcode, I notice that `@interface AppDelegate()` being declared again in `AppDelegate.m` file.

but to be honest, I really don't understand why, I already see `#import "AppDelegate.h"` at begin of `AppDelegate.m` file, why couldn't I directly use `@implementation AppDelegate` after `#import "AppDelegate.m"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference here. The declaration of the AppDelegate Interface in the .m file is actually a class extension. Notice the () after the interface declaration.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3):

> Class extensions are often used to extend the public interface with
>   additional private methods or properties for use within the
>   implementation of the class itself.